# Swift configuring timezone with identifier changes GMT value

Tags: swift, timezone

I have the following playground code:

```
let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
let zurichTimeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/Zurich")
dateFormatter.timeZone = zurichTimeZone
// dateFormatter.timeZone = .init(abbreviation: "GMT+1:00")


// prints timezone +1
print(dateFormatter.string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(100400))))

// prints timezone +2
print(dateFormatter.string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(1665957700))))
```

The first output is **"1970-01-02T04:53:20+01:00"** and the second output is **"2022-10-17T00:01:40+02:00"**. Why does the GMT value change? If use **"Europe/Kalingrad"** as the identifier, I will get **+3** from the first and **+2** from the second print. The problem won't appear when I'm setting the timezone with **"dateFormatter.timeZone = .init(abbreviation: "GMT+1:00")"**. I also can't find this behaviour when I'm using **"Pacific/Guam"**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The named `TimeZone`s take daylight saving time (DST) into consideration, while the ones created by a GMT offset do not.

Zurich is GMT+1 in winter time, but GMT+2 in summer time.

The 2 dates you create are on different sides of the clock change, so 1 uses  summer time, while the other uses winter time. This is where the 1h time difference using the 2 different timezones is coming from.